# SQL View SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query in SQL 2008

```
SELECT [orde_reference],
       SUBSTRING([orde_reference], 
                  CHARINDEX('/', [orde_reference]) + 1, 
                  LEN([orde_reference])) AS batch
FROM   Orders
```

That returns the following

```
orde_reference:        27777/2012/1          
batch:                 2012/1
```

However I need the batch to just be the characters after the last / (there are always 2 x '/' in the varchar

```
orde_reference:        27777/2012/1          
batch:                 1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers
Mim

Comment: Use REVERSE as in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT orde_reference,
       RIGHT(orde_reference, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(orde_reference)) - 1) batch
  FROM orders
```

Sample output:

```
| ORDE_REFERENCE | BATCH |
--------------------------
|   27777/2012/1 |     1 |
|  27734/2013/11 |    11 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3e75b/1)** demo

Comment: @Mim I'm glad I could help :) If it was what you were looking for please, consider to **[accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As there are always 2 `/` you can pass the optional third argument to [`CHARINDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) (`start_location`) to tell it to start looking after the first one.

```
SELECT [orde_reference],
       SUBSTRING([orde_reference], 
                  CHARINDEX('/', [orde_reference],1 + CHARINDEX('/', [orde_reference])) + 1, 
                  LEN([orde_reference])) AS batch
FROM   Orders
```

You would be better off storing these components individually however in separate columns.

Comment: As you said this wouldn't work with another number of "/". While the rESERVE approch give the last "/" splitted part in every case.

Comment: @Serge - Irrelevant though. In this case the OP is parsing a `orde_reference` with a well defined structure. The batch being the 2nd item. If the structure was to change there is no particular reason to assume the batch number would still be the final item.

Answer (score 0):

Use REVERSE twice ;)

```
SELECT [orde_reference]
  ,REVERSE(SUBSTRING(reverse([orde_reference]), 0, CHARINDEX('/', reverse([orde_reference])))) AS batch
  from (values(
  ' 27777/2012/123'
  )) as O([orde_reference])
```